# JTAG'ing firmware into imx28

Tags: embedded, hardware, boot-loader, u-boot

My goal here is to load a custom kernel and initramfs into the memory of the wink hub 1 based on imx28 dev board and boot it using the bootm command from u-boot shell.

So, I downloaded the u-boot 2014.01 source code and built it from scratch using the patch provided [here](http://jalderman.org/?p=348) then I downloaded the latest buildroot and build the kernel and root file system along with initramfs for the imx28 board.

Using JTAG I'm able to load the `u-boot at 0x40000100, kernel at 0x42000000` and `initramfs at 0x42300000` but when I pass these addresses into the u-boot shell and hit bootm the kernel hangs after decompressing and nothing happens...

I thought there might be the problem with the kernel but even when I pass just the kernel address without loading the custom one *( i.e. loading the kernel present in the nand memory )* in the RAM still the kernel hangs and does not boot it only works well with the `boot (bootcmd)` command.

This is the output when trying to load the kernel manually from a memory address nothing happens after decompression.

```
=> bootm 42000000 42300000 
## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 42000000 ...
   Image Name:   Linux-2.6.35.3-flex-dvt
   Created:      2014-04-30   3:15:35 UTC
   Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)
   Data Size:    1928460 Bytes = 1.8 MiB
   Load Address: 40008000
   Entry Point:  40008000
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
## Loading init Ramdisk from Legacy Image at 42300000 ...
   Image Name:   Root Filesystem
   Created:      2019-01-12  14:23:44 UTC
   Image Type:   ARM Linux RAMDisk Image (uncompressed)
   Data Size:    893637 Bytes = 872.7 KiB
   Load Address: 40800000
   Entry Point:  40800000
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
   Loading Kernel Image ... OK

Starting kernel ...

Uncompressing Linux... done, booting the kernel.
```

But on the u-boot shell just after hitting `boot` command it boots and everything works fine.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong I've checked the `/include/configs/mx28evk.h` for the kernel uImage, initramfs & fdt addresses and everything seems right.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out what the problem was.

I had enabled low level debugging and had redirected all printk's to Embedded ICE UART port so it would not show any output on the UART console.

```
[ ] Kernel low-level debugging functions 
      [ ] Early printk (NEW)
      [ ] Kernel low-level debugging via EmbeddedICE DCC channel (NEW)
```

keep it unselected as above.

Regards,
Amit.